# should I use a static method in the interceptor to put some global data in spring cloud gateway

Tags: java

Now I have some put global data logic in the spring cloud gateway interceptor `JwtAuthenticationGatewayFilterFactory` like this:

```
public static void setRequestGlobalHeader(String token, ServerWebExchange exchange, ServerHttpRequest request) {
        Claims claims = AuthUtil.getClaimFromToken(token);
        RequestContext.initMDC();
        RequestContext.putLoginId(MapUtils.getLongValue(claims, "userId", 0L));
        RequestContext.putAppId(MapUtils.getIntValue(claims, "appId", -1));
        RequestContext.putDeviceId(MapUtils.getString(claims, "deviceId", "unknown"));

        exchange.getRequest()
                .mutate()
                .header("id", String.valueOf(claims.get("id")))
                .header("appId", String.valueOf(claims.get("appId")))
                .header("userId", String.valueOf(claims.get("userId")))
                .header("accessToken", token)
                .header("x-access-token", token)
                .header("X-Request-ID", request.getHeaders().getFirst(AuthHeaderKey.REQUEST_ID))
                .build();
    }
```

I am facing a JVM out of memory problem right now, this is the log:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3776) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:172) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:538) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:174) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.URLStreamHandler.toExternalForm(URLStreamHandler.java:473) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.URL.toExternalForm(URL.java:1044) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.URL.toString(URL.java:1030) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.Handler.isUrlInJarFile(Handler.java:102) ~[dolphin-gateway-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.Handler.openConnection(Handler.java:88) ~[dolphin-gateway-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at java.net.URL.openConnection(URL.java:1099) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath$Loader.findResource(URLClassPath.java:737) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath$1.next(URLClassPath.java:445) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath$1.hasMoreElements(URLClassPath.java:455) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$2$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:894) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$2$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:892) ~[?:?]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:708) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$2.next(URLClassLoader.java:891) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$2.hasMoreElements(URLClassLoader.java:916) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader$UseFastConnectionExceptionsEnumeration.hasMoreElements(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:336) ~[dolphin-gateway-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$CompoundEnumeration.hasMoreElements(ClassLoader.java:773) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.nextProviderClass(ServiceLoader.java:1203) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNextService(ServiceLoader.java:1221) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1265) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$2.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1300) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$3.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1385) ~[?:?]
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.lang.Services.loadAll(Services.java:80) ~[jjwt-impl-0.11.2.jar!/:0.11.2]
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.lang.Services.loadAll(Services.java:68) ~[jjwt-impl-0.11.2.jar!/:0.11.2]
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.compression.DefaultCompressionCodecResolver.<init>(DefaultCompressionCodecResolver.java:60) ~[jjwt-impl-0.11.2.jar!/:0.11.2]
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.<init>(DefaultJwtParser.java:72) ~[jjwt-impl-0.11.2.jar!/:0.11.2]
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParserBuilder.build(DefaultJwtParserBuilder.java:194) ~[jjwt-impl-0.11.2.jar!/:0.11.2]
    at misc.util.AuthUtil.getClaimFromToken(AuthUtil.java:257) ~[dolphin-common-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-plain.jar!/:?]
    at misc.util.AuthUtil.setRequestGlobalHeader(AuthUtil.java:292) ~[dolphin-common-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-plain.jar!/:?]
    at com.dolphin.gateway.filter.JwtAuthenticationGatewayFilterFactory.authImpl(JwtAuthenticationGatewayFilterFactory.java:71) ~[classes!/:?]
    at com.dolphin.gateway.filter.JwtAuthenticationGatewayFilterFactory.lambda$apply$2(JwtAuthenticationGatewayFilterFactory.java:49) ~[classes!/:?]
    at com.dolphin.gateway.filter.JwtAuthenticationGatewayFilterFactory$$Lambda$1082/0x00000000840484a0.filter(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.OrderedGatewayFilter.filter(OrderedGatewayFilter.java:44) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-server-3.0.3.jar!/:3.0.3]
    at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.handler.FilteringWebHandler$DefaultGatewayFilterChain.lambda$filter$0(FilteringWebHandler.java:117) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-server-3.0.3.jar!/:3.0.3]
    at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.handler.FilteringWebHandler$DefaultGatewayFilterChain$$Lambda$1131/0x00000000b001c3b0.get(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
```

is the static method problem? the variable did not dispose when the request ended? what should I do to avoid the OOM problem? This is my code about `getClaimFromToken`:

```
   public static Claims getClaimFromToken(String token) {
        try {
            Jws<Claims> claimsJws = Jwts.parserBuilder().setSigningKey(JWT_SIGN_KEY.getBytes()).build()
                    .parseClaimsJws(token);
            return claimsJws.getBody();
        } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
            throw GlobalException.ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRED_EXCEPTION;
        } catch (JwtException e) {
            throw GlobalException.ACCESS_TOKEN_INVALID_EXCEPTION;
        }
    }
```

Comment: you are getting this error in which line of your code?

Comment: `Claims claims = AuthUtil.getClaimFromToken(token);` this line, I found many places throw this error, so I tried to dump the memory and analysis using MAT. @mystery

Comment: Then show code of this method..may be there is a problem

Comment: I have pasted my cod about `getClaimFromToken` @mystery

Comment: What is the analysis result of MAT? Which object takes up a lot of memory